# Alter table ID , but code is not working?

Tags: mysql

I need to set the ID counter to a different value, but it seem's like the table isn't set up correctly?

I've triedtried:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Here is the table view.

```
1   I_ID    int(11)         No  None    AUTO_INCREMENT  Change Change   Drop
```

What is causing the issue, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: You have to set the auto increment flag of the column, not the table.

Comment: Why do you  need to do this anyway?

Comment: i need it for my POS..need to start the Invoice number from were they are at in the papers..